# Defer regular properties in OData

Tags: odata

In the OData protocol, there is a way to defer representing navigation properties (i.e. links to a particular resource or collection) so the server doesn't return extra data to the client.

My question is, can I do the same thing for regular properties?  I have a data structure which has a property that takes the server a long time to compute and I would like the client to not receive the value by default.

The property is logically part of the entity and is NOT a navigation property.  In the OData documentation anywhere I've seen deferred content its about deferring navigation property.  Wanted to know if it's possible to defer regular properties and if not, what are my alternative options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible.

Alternatively you could isolate the computed properties into another entity (say, tear up MyEntity into MyEntity and MyEntityCalculations). Then you can reuse your original entity's ID as an ID of the second entity.

So if you have an instance myEntity with ID = 32, then you could have an instance myEntityCalculations, also with ID = 32, which then contains the calculated properties only.

Comment: Does this mean myEntityCalculations needs to have an additional property named ID as well since it needs to be the key?  Or is there some way to say myEntityCalculations' ID refers to myEntity's ID?

Comment: Of course, you need to share the ID -- so both entities have an ID property.

Answer (score 1):

You can use projection on the client and you'll receive only the projected properties.
But you won't get a link to the non-projected property, this is implemented only for navigation properties.

Hope this helps,

Monica Frintu